# Add numbers generated from json data in javascript then displayed with Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I need to add some numbers together that I am generating from json data using javascript and displaying using Vue. I am not sure how to do some simple addition with these values as it seems I can't affect them with javascript after they are created.

I've tried a whole bunch of math, innerHTML and then adding them, giving the div classes and trying to add the numbers, I tried reduce functions but kept getting undefined. Essentially I've tried all sorts of things that simply don't work or I may be doing incorrectly.

Here's the Javascript that created a table from which I want to get the numbers:

```
function buildDeliveryTable() {
    let rDeliveries = [];
    let jobs = currStop.Jobs;
    for (let job of jobs) {
        for (let item of job.Items) {
            if (isDelivery(item)) {
                let type = item.ItemName;
                let itemCount = undefined;
                for (let attri of item.FieldDataValues) {
                    if (attri.Id == "95820") {
                        itemCount = attri.Double;
                    } else {
                        itemCount = attri.Strings.length;
                    }
                }
                rDeliveries.push({
                    type: type,
                    itemCount: itemCount
                });
            }
        }
    }
    return rDeliveries;
}
```

The function is looking through the json and outputting the attributes above. In one case it's simply displaying the attributes, in the other, it's adding the number of strings up and displaying that. I need to add the total of the attributes and the strings.

The table is simply called with a function later on, nothing fancy.

```
mlData.deliveries = buildDeliveryTable(mlData);
```

Here is the Vue, again, nothing fancy:

```
<table class="dataTable">
    <tr class="font1Bold">
        <td>Item</td>
        <td class="alignRight">Qty</td>
    </tr>
    <tr v-for="delivery in deliveries">
        <td>{{delivery.type}}</td>
        <td>{{delivery.itemCount}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I need to get the total of the values that are output in delivery.itemCount. I am not sure how.

I would like to get the total (sum) of the values in delivery.itemCount. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you able to add to your question the value of the variable `mlData` that you're passing into the `buildDeliveryTable` method?

Comment: That's a great question. mlData is allowing me to call the json data. Everything on the js side is inside a window.processMlxReceipt = function (mlData) { function. The setup is very strange because of the viewer we use to create and test the output. The mlData shouldn't have an effect on the function I'm trying to put together.

Comment: There are a few issues with your question: you pass `mlData` to your `buildDeliveryTable` function, but in the definition there is no variable. And you reference `deliveries` in your html template, even though there is no such variable earlier. You should try and do a [mcve]. JSFiddle has a good Vue boilerplate for that: https://jsfiddle.net/boilerplate/vue.

Comment: @UlysseBN trust me, I have to pass mlData due to the html viewer. deliveries is referenced in mlData.deliveries and the actual display of the array works totally fine. Definitely appreciate the feedback though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you could use a [computed](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html) value that takes the sum of all your `itemCount` within deliveries:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    deliveries: [
      { type: "bananas", itemCount: 12 },
      { type: "apples", itemCount: 21 },
      { type: "coconuts", itemCount: 5 },
      { type: "tomatoes", itemCount: 4 }
    ]
  },
  computed: {
    totalItemCount () {
      return  this.deliveries.reduce((sum, { itemCount }) => sum + itemCount, 0)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="delivery in deliveries">
      {{ delivery.type }} - {{ delivery.itemCount }}
    </li>
  </ul>
  <p>
    Total: {{ totalItemCount }}
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: I wish I could do this, as this is how I would normally manage an issue like this with Vue, but I can't use a Vue instance here and I am also getting the itemCount using those if statements in the original javascript I posted. Could I use a reduce function on the itemCount in some other way maybe? This has been plaguing me for weeks and I can't seem to find an answer that applies to how I have to do this.

Comment: I'm sorry but I won't be able to help you more without clarification of the question and a [mcve]...

Comment: I get it, unfortunately I can't get you the code behind the viewer that I have to use. I am part of a larger project. I appreciate the attempt to help.

Comment: I know what a minimal reproducible example would be, but to manage the Vue compiler I would essentially have to copy and paste the entire thing. Using a vue method or computed property doesn't work. It's a dumb way to do things, but it is what it is. It's not a proprietary issue, it's a "I can't rebuild the code that renders the code" issue. I solved my problem by basically rebuilding all the data. Thank you again for your help, in most cases, your answer would be completely correct, so I've marked it correct.